# Create Dropdown field form from List with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

During the next time, I could create some posts because I'm learning `C#` and `ASP.NET MVC`. I'm coming from Pythonic world, so some things are not clear for me.

I would like to generate a List of strings, then I would like to display this list in my form as a DropDownList.

This is my model:

```
public class Joueur
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Nom"), StringLength(30)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Prénom"), StringLength(30)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(15)]
        public string Poste { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller according to Create Method:

```
// GET: Joueurs/Create
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<Strings> posteList = new List<SelectListItem>{ "Gardien", "Défenseur", "Milieu", "Attaquant" };
            ViewBag.PosteList = posteList;
            return View();
        }
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @*ViewBag.PosteList is holding all the postes values*@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Poste, ViewBag.PosteList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Poste, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

But I get this issue:

> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Poste, ViewBag.PosteList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
>   There is no ViewData element of type « IEnumerable » with the key « Poste ».

How I could do that ?

With Django, it's pretty easy, in my model I create a dictionary and I pass this dict in the property, but with C# ASP.NET? I don't find a way to do that.

Comment: You are not sending the `Joueur` class as a Model to the View it would seem. Seehttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your view will display a form to represent the `Joueur` object that you want the user to fill out, and your `ViewBag.PosteList` will have the values that the user can select from for the `Joueur.Poste` property. In order to accomplish this, you should create a new/empty `Joueur` object in your `Create` controller method and pass it to the view like so:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Joueur();
    List<Strings> posteList = new List<SelectListItem>{ "Gardien", "Défenseur", "Milieu", "Attaquant" };
    ViewBag.PosteList = posteList;
    return View(model);
}
```

Then the rest of your original code should work.

Comment: It's exactly what I would like to do, but It doesn't work. I found the solution. It was my edit part, but I haven't make the migration. As I'm learning C# ASP.NET and Visual Studio, lot of things are unclear yet for me. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, hopefully it's a good way:

In my model I created an `Enum`:

```
public class Joueur
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Nom"), StringLength(30)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Prénom"), StringLength(30)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(15)]
        public Position Poste { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Position
    {
        Gardien,
        Défenseur,
        Milieu,
        Attaquant
    }
```

And in my view I added:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Poste, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Poste, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(FCSL.Models.Joueur.Position))), "Sélectionner le poste", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Poste, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And I applied migration commands. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Poste", new SelectList(  ViewBag.PosteList, "id", "Poste"))
```

and in controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    List<Strings> posteList = new List<SelectListItem>{ "Gardien", "Défenseur", "Milieu", "Attaquant" };
    ViewBag.PosteList = posteList;
    return View(ViewBag.PosteList);  // return viewbag 
}
```